# join vector of non-strings into a string rust

Tags: rust

I have a type T that implements display (so it has a `.to_string()` method)

```rs
let my_vec = vec![T(), T(), T()];
println!("{}", my_vec.join(", "));
```

sadly errors with "trait bounds not satisfied" because the separator, `", "`, is not of the same type as the vector's items (I'm pretty sure).

I guess my workaround is then

```rs
println!("{}", my_vec.iter().map(|x| x.to_string()).collect::<Vec<_>>().join(", "));
```

But isn't there anything shorter and clearer that I can write out instead of this?

---

I've just written this function to help me out:

```rs
fn join<T, I>(vec: &[T], sep: I) -> String
where
    T: std::fmt::Display,
    I: std::fmt::Display,
{
    vec.iter().map(|x| x.to_string()).collect::<Vec<_>>().join(&sep.to_string())
}
```

But I'd rather not have to. There must be alternative solutions that: are already built-in, don't require manual implementation, at least don't require the creation of a top-level function that's then only called twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, your work around is good and sound without non-std libs.

Several cargos provide some helper functions for this issue, for example:

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9627cba33c63e042693d7fb5cdeae264)

[itertools](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.join) and [joinery](https://docs.rs/joinery/latest/joinery/)

```
use itertools::Itertools;
use joinery::Joinable;

struct Color {
    red: u8,
    green: u8,
    blue: u8,
}

impl std::fmt::Display for Color {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(
            f,
            "RGB ({}, {}, {}) 0x{:02X}{:02X}{:02X}",
            self.red, self.green, self.blue, self.red, self.green, self.blue
        )
    }
}

fn main() {
    let colors = vec![
        Color {
            red: 128,
            green: 255,
            blue: 90,
        },
        Color {
            red: 0,
            green: 3,
            blue: 254,
        },
    ];

    println!(
        "{}",
        colors
            .iter()
            .map(|x| x.to_string())
            .collect::<Vec<_>>()
            .join(", ")
    );

    println!("{}", colors.iter().join(", "));
    println!("{}", colors.join_with(", "));
}
```